# php require failed to open stream:

Tags: php

I'm having a problem regarding the access to ros ezpdf using composer

[image: My structure]

Now i want using the green file (requisicoesDiarias.php) showed in the image, i want to access the red one (dbconfig.php) to get the result from a query and then show this result in a pdf (blue folder)
What i have until now is this

```
include_once '../../../db/dbconfig.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
set_include_path('../vendor/ros/ezpdf/src/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

I have the following errors

```
Warning: include_once(/home/ebspma/public_html/gest/pages/multimedia/pdf../../../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ebspma/public_html/gest/pages/multimedia/pdf/requisicoesDiarias.php on line 7
Warning: include_once(/home/ebspma/public_html/gest/vendor/ros/ezpdf/src): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ebspma/public_html/gest/pages/multimedia/pdf/requisicoesDiarias.php on line 8
```

I have put a file in that folder ros->ezpdf->src to get current path and i have this
/home/xxxxx/public_html/gest/vendor/ros/ezpdf/src

any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: is this still an issue? As I am the developer of this library I really want to know any issues